# Is the remainder term in a Taylor polynomial approximation for $\log{(1+x)}$ correct in Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 20?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, polynomials, taylor-expansion

In Chapter 20 of Spivak's *Calculus* 4th edition page 427 is written

> From the calculations on page 413, we see that for $x\geq 0$ we have
>
> $$\log{(1+x)}=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+...+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}t^{n+1}\tag{1}$$
>
> where $$\left | \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}t^{n+1}\right |\leq \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$
>
> and there is a slightly more complicated estimate when $-1<x<0$
> (Problem 16).

As far as I can tell the last term in $(1)$ $$\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}t^{n+1}\tag{2}$$ is the remainder term when we use a Taylor polynomial approximation.

However, isn't this remainder supposed to be

$$R_{n,0}(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}(x-0)^{n+1}, t\in (0,x)$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^n \cdot n!}{(1+t)^{n+1}}\cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\cdot x^{n+1}, t\in (0,x)$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^n x^{n+1}}{(1+t)^{n+1}(n+1)}\tag{3}$$

?

I used

$$f^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^{k-1} \frac{(k-1)!}{(1+x)^k}$$

thus

$$f^{(k+1)}(t)=(-1)^{k} \frac{k!}{(1+t)^{k+1}}$$

Am I making some silly mistake here?

Is the remainder term $(2)$ or $(3)$?

Comment: Note that for $x\geq0$ the series is alternating. The sum $S$ of the series will be between the partial sum $S_n$ up to the $n$-degree term, and the sum $S_{n+1} $adding the next term $(-1)^nx^{n+1}/(n+1)$. The continuity of $(-1)^nt^{n+1}/(n+1)$, and the Intermediate Value Theorem, tell you there is some $t$ such that $(-1)^nt^{n+1}/(n+1)=S-S_n$.

Comment: I had the same question before. Thank you very much for your question.

Comment: @user85667 The Taylor polynomial approximation alternates between having the last term positive and a negative remainder, and a last term negative and a positive remainder. The difference $S_{n+1}-S_n$ is just the difference between the Taylor polynomials, ie just the last term in $S_{n+1}$, which is $(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$. If we view the latter term as a function of $x$, then it is continuous. How are you using the IVT?

Comment: Note that if all there is going to be is a $t$ that is guaranteed to exist but not much more is said about it, then as the remainder you can put anything, as long as you can prove that some value of $t$ will make it take the right value. For example, $t$ or $t^3$ could be the the expression for the remainder of all Taylor of all functions. So, don't get limited by the classic forms of the remainder. Of course, to say more about $t$, like $t\in(0,x)$ one needs a better chosen expression.

Comment: You know that in a series that satisfies the alternating series test, the sum $S$ is between two consecutive partial sums, for example $S_n\leq S\leq S_{n+1}$. The inequalities reverse or not depending on the parity of $n$. Note that adding $(-1)^{n}x^{n+1}/(n+1)$ is adding the full next term and getting $S_{n+1}$, while adding $0$ is staying on $S_n$. Since $t\to S_n+(-1)^nt^{n+1}/(n+1)$ is continuous, it will take all values in between, in particular, the value $S$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spivak did not make this clear. He is not applying the remainder formula. He's illustrating that in some cases you can do better than the formula. (He's been through a very similar argument with $\arctan$ just before this point.) It's crucial here that we have $x\ge 0$. Starting with our usual
$$\frac1{1+u} = 1-u+u^2+\dots+ (-1)^{n-1}u^{n-1} + (-1)^n \frac{u^n}{1+u}$$
and integrating, we have
$$\log(1+x) = x-\frac{x^2}2+\dots+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}n + (-1)^n\int_0^x \frac{u^n}{1+u}du.$$
Now, for $x>0$ we have
$$0<\int_0^x \frac{u^n}{1+u}du < \int_0^x u^n\,du = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}.$$
It follows from the Intermediate Value Theorem that
$$\int_0^x \frac{u^n}{1+u}du = \frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1} \quad \text{for some } 0<t<x.$$

Comment: Professor Shifrin, Thank you very much for your answer. I had the same question before. Now I understand it.

Comment: How precisely is the Intermediate Value Theorem used? You stated that $\int_0^x \frac{u^n}{1+u}du<\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$, but how does this imply that $\int_0^x \frac{u^n}{1+u}du=\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}$ for some $0<t<x$?

Comment: You should be able to prove that. Consider the function $f(sj=s^{n+1}/(n+1)$ on $[0,x]$.

Comment: Is it because if $f(x)=\int_0^x \frac{u^n}{1+u}$ and $g(x)=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ then $f(0)=g(0)=0$, both functions are continuous, for all $x>0$ we have $0<f(x)<g(x)$, and therefore, by the IVT, $g$ assumes all values between $0$ and $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ on $[0,x]$, including all the values between $0$ and $f(x)<\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$? Therefore, there is a $t\in (0,x)$ such that $g(t)=f(x)$.

Comment: You are making it too complicated. $x$ is fixed here and your $f(x)$ is just a number. Look at my $f(s)$ as I suggested.

Comment: Let $f(s):=\frac{s^{n+1}}{n+1}$ and $c:=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{u^n}{1+u}\,du$. Then $f(s)$ is a continuous function on $[0,x]$ and $f(0)=0<c<\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=f(x)$. So, by the IVT, there is some $t$ in $(0,x)$ such that $\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}=f(t)=c=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{u^n}{1+u}\,du$.

Comment: @evianpring Please accept this answer now that you are satisfied that you understand. The site should not be cluttered up with seemingly "unanswered" questions.

Comment: I took a break from studying for a few days, and coincidentally, I am back just today. I will accept this answer because I am satisfied with it. Most of my questions receive multiple answers, and usually none are absolutely complete answers, so I leave them open. I don't really like the "accepted answer" feature of Stack Exchange. After the information contained in the votes, the OP accepting an answer doesn't usually add much information, though occasionally a very complete answer comes up where not only is it correct, but it is didactical. Thanks for providing one such answer and follow-ups.

Comment: Thanks for verbalizing that. I think there are too many reputation fiends/hogs. However, I personally am inclined to stop trying to help people if they don't say some form of "thank you" when I invest the time. Indeed, if my answers don't help, then you should not accept and I won't continue to interact. ... BTW, as I said at the beginning, this issue definitely was something screwy on Spivak's part. I no longer have my copies of the first three editions; I wonder if something got changed in the last edition.

Comment: Indeed, he did rewrite that chapter significantly (he had emphasized the integral form of the remainder in the earlier treatment, and I talked him into just doing the Lagrange form). (Sadly, Spivak has died, so there will be no further editions.) Anyhow, good question!