# Spivak: Understanding computation of an upper bound for remainder of Taylor polynomial approximation of $\log{(1+x)}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, taylor-expansion

There is a particular calculation in Spivak's *Calculus* that I had to think about a lot. I think I finally understood it but I am not sure about why it was done this way.

The calculation is related to [another recent question that I asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4513398/is-the-remainder-term-in-a-taylor-polynomial-approximation-for-log1x-cor) about computing the remainder term in a Taylor polynomial approximation to $\log{(1+x)}$.

The conclusion of that question was how to compute the remainder term in the following expression, for $x\geq 0$

$$\log{(1+x)}=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+...+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}t^{n+1}, t\in (0,x)$$

where

$$|R_{n,0}(x)|=\left | \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}t^{n+1} \right |\leq \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \tag{1}$$

and $R_{n,0}(x)$ is the remainder term. Some work was involved in coming up with the remainder above (which is obtained from the integral form of the remainder), instead of just applying the formula for the Lagrange remainder (which I will do below).

Then Spivak says

> and there is a slightly more complicated estimate when $-1<x<0$
> (Problem 16). For this function the remainder term can be made as small as desired by choosing $n$ sufficiently large, provided that $-1<x\leq 1$.

The "slightly more complicated estimate when $-1<x<0$ turns out to be

$$\left | \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}t^{n+1} \right |\leq \frac{x^{n+1}}{(1+x)(n+1)}\tag{2}$$

Let's see what happens if we use the Lagrange form of the remainder. We have

$$R_{n,0}(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{(n+1)!}(x-0)^{n+1}, t\in (0,x)$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^n \cdot n!}{(1+t)^{n+1}}\cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\cdot x^{n+1}, t\in (0,x)$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^n x^{n+1}}{(1+t)^{n+1}(n+1)}, t\in (0,x)\tag{3}$$

the magnitude of which is smaller than $\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n+1}$, and we can see this also can be made as small as desired.

**Why didn't Spivak just use this remainder to make the points he made, namely that for $-1<x\leq 1$ the remainder is decreasing in $n$? He could have, correct?**

Now, the reason we need to come up with an upper bound for the remainder is so that we have an expression that is dependent on quantities we know ($x$ and $n$), and not quantities we don't know ($t$), correct?

Here is how we obtain $(2)$:

For $-1<x\leq t\leq 0$ we have

$$0<1+x\leq 1+t\leq 1$$

$$0\leq \frac{1}{1+t}\leq \frac{1}{1+x}$$

$$\left | \int_0^x\frac{u^n}{1+u}du\right |\leq \int_0^x \frac{|u|^n}{1+x}du\leq \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(1+x)(n+1)}$$

**But is the following calculation also correct?** EDIT: no, the following is incorrect.

The integral form of the remainder is $\int_0^x (-1)^n \frac{u^n}{1+u}du$

Assume $-1<x\leq 0$, $n$ is odd and let $f(x)=-\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$.

Then

$$f(0)=0>\int_x^0 \frac{u^n}{1+u}du>\int_x^0 u^n du = -\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=f(x)\tag{4}$$

And the Intermediate Value Theorem tells us that there exists some $t\in (x,0)$ such that $-\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}=\int_x^0 \frac{u^n}{1+u}du$.

Thus, the remainder term is

$$R_{n,0}=(-1)^{n} \int_0^x \frac{u^n}{1+u}du=(-1)\cdot \frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}<0$$

$$-\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}<-\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}=R_{n,0}(x)<0$$

Hence

$$|R_{n,0}(x)|<\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Now assume $n$ is even. Then

$$f(0)=0<\int_x^0\frac{u^n}{1+u}du<\int_x^0 u^ndu=-\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=f(x)$$

Again, the Intermediate Value Theorem tells us that there exists some $t\in (x,0)$ such that $-\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}=\int_x^0 \frac{u^n}{1+u}du$.

Therefore,

$$R_{n,0}=(-1)^{n} \int_0^x \frac{u^n}{1+u}du= \frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}<0$$

$$\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}<\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}=R_{n,0}(x)<0$$

Hence

$$|R_{n,0}(x)|<\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

**EDIT:** as per Ted Shifrin's comment, these calculations don't, in fact, work. The reason is that the integrals are all for $|x|<1$, and so $\frac{1}{1+u}>1$.

**Thus, inequalities like in $(4)$ don't work.**

Comment: Since $-1<u<0$, the inequalities don't work at all. In particular, $1+u<1$ and so $\frac 1{1+u}>1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your specific question (as Dr. Shifrin already addressed this in his comments) but I figured I would use this question as an opportunity to clean up the solution manual's argument (as it is very terse).

As indicated by Ted Shifrin on the answer to your previous post ([Is the remainder term in a Taylor polynomial approximation for $\log{(1+x)}$ correct in Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 20?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4513398/is-the-remainder-term-in-a-taylor-polynomial-approximation-for-log1x-cor)) the most general Taylor Polynomial plus remainder form for $\log(1+x)$ is:

> $\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots+(-1)^{n}\frac{x^n}{n}+(-1)^n \int_0^x \frac{u^{n}}{1+u}du$

The above formula is valid $\forall x \gt -1$.

Note that $(-1)^n \int_0^x \frac{u^{n}}{1+u}du$ is a specific formulation of $R_{n,0,\log(1+I)}(x)$, the remainder term.

Next, consider the following argument, which only uses information derived from previous chapters within the book:
\begin{align}\left|(-1)^n \int_0^x \frac{u^{n}}{1+u}du\right|&=\left|\int_0^x \frac{u^{n}}{1+u}du\right| \\
&=\left|-\int_x^0\frac{u^n}{1+u}du\right|\\
&=\left|\int_x^0\frac{u^n}{1+u}du\right|\\
&\leq\int_x^0\left|\frac{u^n}{1+u}\right|du\end{align}

Given that $x \in (-1,0]$, we know that $1+u$ will only ever evaluate to a positive number, so we can continue with:

\begin{align} \int_x^0\left|\frac{u^n}{1+u}\right|du=\int_x^0\frac{\left|u^n\right|}{1+u}du\end{align}

In the context of this integral, for some fixed $x \in (-1,0]$, there will be an interval of different $u$'s that participate in the $\frac{1}{1+u}$ function. Specifically, given the upper bound of integration $0$, the interval of $u$'s (call it $\mathcal U$) can be represented as $\mathcal U=[x,0]$. As such, for any $u \in\mathcal U$, the following properties are satisfied:

$-1 \lt x \leq u \leq 0 \implies 0 \lt x+1\leq u+1 \leq 1 \implies 1\leq \frac{1}{u+1} \leq \frac{1}{x+1}$

Therefore, the following inequality is completely valid:

$$\int_x^0\frac{\left|u^n\right|}{1+u}du \leq \int_x^0\frac{\left|u^n\right|}{1+x}du$$

Importantly, the $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is no longer a function involving the variable $u$ (i.e. from the perspective of the function *within* the integral, it is a constant), and we are permitted to remove it from the integral as such:

$$\int_x^0 \frac{\left|u^n\right|}{1+x}du=\frac{1}{1+x}\int_x^0  \left|u^n \right|du$$

Of course, the integral that remains allows for the overall expression to be easily evaluated as:

$$\frac{1}{1+x}\int_x^0  \left|u^n \right|du=\frac{1}{1+x}\times \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

We conclude that:

$$\left| R_{n,0,\log(1+I)}(x)\right|= \left| (-1)^n \int_0^x \frac{u^{n}}{1+u}du\right| \leq \frac{1}{1+x}\times \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n+1}$$